# Port forwarding issue

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, portforwarding

I have `Totolink A2004NS` wifi router, to which I have connected a desktop PC with static IP configured.

I have got the static IP address from the ISP. I need to host a web service on port 80.

When I try to port forward External port 80 to Internal port 80, I get a error message saying -

`Port number can not contain Web port`.

*Screenshot attached.*

However, other port forwards work just fine.

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

Comment: Check if router expose own web interface on public address. If yes, disable it and try again. If no this is the design of firmware

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Yes. My router exposes a web port. I am not sure where to disable it. I have looked into all the menus/options in router web portal. Cannot spot a setting for it.

Comment: Have you try with port trigger instead of forward?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - I figured it out. I had it under WAN Settings. Changed the port from 80 to 8081 and I was then able to port forward 80. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. If you change the web port of the wifi router from the WAN settings, you will be able to port forward to 80.